# Trying to parse out the $_POST key names that I don't want

Tags: php

```
$post_keys = array_keys($_POST);
$special_keys = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($post_keys);$i++){
    if(strpos($post_keys[$i], "special") !== false){

        $special_keys[] = $post_keys[$i];

    }
}
```

I have numerous post vars with naming conventions such as special0, special0_time, special0_duration, special1, special1_time etc.... What I want to do is to find out how many main groups there are, so special0, special1 etc... The code I currently have searches all key names that have "special" in it, thus retrieving more than I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gumbo is correct, however if you still need to perform such a task, regex can help:

```
if(preg_match('/^(?<key>special[0-9]+)_/ix', $post_keys[$i], $match)){
    $special_keys[] = $match['key'];
}
```

After which you can run `array_unique()` on `$special_keys` to get an array of groups.

Answer (score 2):

PHP already builds an array for parameters that uses the array like syntax (e.g. `arg[]`). See [*How do I create arrays in a HTML `<form>`?*](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Comment: thanks. Would have saved me a lot of work. I will do it this way from now on

Answer (score 0):

For easier maintenance try this structure:

```
$_POST = array(
  'special' => array(
       array('time'=>, 'duration'=>, ''=>),
       array('time'=>, 'duration'=>, ''=>),
       array('time'=>, 'duration'=>, ''=>),
  ),
);
```

Then you can do stuff like count($_POST['special']) and $_POST['special'][1]['time']